# Downvotes on answers becuase they come from the tools author?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21353/are-there-any-tools-to-automatically-search-and-download-literature-in-a-given/)
asks about the tools to do a particular task.

[This answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21353/are-there-any-tools-to-automatically-search-and-download-literature-in-a-given/26993#26993), is down voted quiet alot.

It is by the author of said tool.
On other sites in the StackExchange network my experience has been that it is allowed, to mention tools that you happen to be the creator of -- if it is a valid answer.

- [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/clarification-of-level-of-personal-involvement-in-a-software-project/771#771)
- [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220289/how-can-i-promote-a-self-written-tool-on-stackoverflow)

To me that answer seems to be at least on par with the others:

1. It goes into some detail about the difficulties of the question.
2. It recommends a tool
3. It explains briefly how to use the tool to solve the problems of the author.

The other answers also recommend tools (Point 2),
and some do go into some details about some issues (Point 1).

He did the right thing in making it clear in his answer that he made the tool in question. It is also on his profile.

So was the answer downvoted because it is self-promotion?
Or is it actually flawed in some other way that I could not see?
Does this site have slightly different standards on self-promotion to other SE sites? (Which is Ok, SE sites are allowed to be different).

to be fair, people are allowed to downvote for what ever reasons they like, and are not required to explain themselves (and I think this is a good thing.)
But I want to know how this community as a whole generally feels about self-promotion, in service of others.

---

The author also recommends [his tool here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16057/what-is-a-fast-way-to-get-the-reference-in-a-specific-style/26994#26994), which is again fairly tailored to the question (as recommended on the [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220289/how-can-i-promote-a-self-written-tool-on-stackoverflow) I linked earlier).
Though in that question the other answers are of fairly high quality.
In that case while his answer may be less good than some other, it is not a bad answer, just less good.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the edit history a substantial edit was made by the author of the answer 7 hours after it was originally made. In my opinion, the answer prior to the edit was worthy of a down vote. Similarly, the answer as it currently stands does not seems worthy of down votes, and probably deserves some up votes. If I remember the time line of the voting, I think the down votes happened end before the edit.

I think the [behavior page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) accurately sums up our views of self promotion:

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Comment: The [thread timeline](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/21353/timeline) mostly confirms this. All the upvotes are after the edit. It's unclear whether the downvotes were before or after, but it's likely they were before it.